# how activate venv on production

Tags: python, node.js, python-venv

I have a backend app based on Node.js. The code is writen on JavaScript, except on folders 'scripts' which it is on Python.

I have some external libraries installed (pandas, matplotlib...) to execute those scripts and I used the virtual env (venv) to use them it correctly.

However, I always need to activate 'source venv/bin/activate' before to execute them (when I am in localhost).

The problem is in production.

Is there any way to let them activate permanently on production? Or other extra software? I hosted these files on VPS in Hostinger, but on production I got some errors in scripts which has some libraries installed.

This 'activate' might be the problem.

[image]

Comment: What's the issue with just activating the venv in your production environment?

Comment: Since you (hopefully) are running the app as a regular user in the production VPS too, you _could_ set up that user's `.bash_profile` to run `activate` automatically, so when you switch to that user, you'll always have an active venv.

Comment: actually i do not know how to activate it on production! I have a frontend which calls this backend. If I activate the venv once on production i do not need to activate it later? It will be always on?

Comment: Ok, @AKX! Could you please teach me how to add this .bash_profile? Where do I put the code to execute always automatically?

Comment: I don't know what you've done so far to deploy your app, but assuming it's e.g. run by an user `app`, and the virtualenv is `/home/app/venv`, you'd put `source /home/app/venv/bin/activate` in the file `/home/app/.bash_profile`.

Comment: ok, bash_profile file and the source code created! But how could I execute the bash_profile automatically for each terminal openned? Could you also help me with this?

Comment: You already helped a lot ;)

Comment: However, I need to type in terminal 'source .bash_profile' to execute source venv/bin/activate

Comment: The `.bash_profile` file should be automatically sourced by Bash. If not, try `.bashrc` instead...

Comment: thanks for the help, AKX! But it's not executing when I open a new terminal. I tried to modified a lot but same result. I'll put a new photo in the question with more details of my project and with your tip.

Comment: only execute venv when i put on terminal 'source ./.bashrc'

Comment: The file needs to be in the user's home directory, and this was **solely for production**, and I doubt `joao-Aspire-A525-566` is your production server – your development workstation probably already has a `.bashrc`. If you need something for your local environment, see e.g. `virtualenvwrapper`, which has a `workon` command.

Comment: I got it! I was doing on dev env indeed. All the same code on production worked fine. Thanks for the help and your patience ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the comments an answer:

- In production, you'll be running your app proper with a service manager such as systemd (that makes sure it stays running). You can direct the service manager to directly use the venv's Python, e.g. `/home/app/venv/bin/python myapp.py`; you don't need the `activate` script.
- To have the virtualenv automatically activated for ad-hoc use on the production server, you can use a `.bashrc` file, e.g. `/home/app/.bashrc` that includes `source ~/venv/bin/activate`.